# Determine when the actual width/height of an element is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

I'm dealing with some modals that are opened up in an iframe (same domain, so no xss issues). One of the modals I have either hides or shows options based on things you do which grows or shrinks the form. Anyway, long story short I have the code that handles resizing the iframe based on the current height/width of the body on the inital load. The problem is that I'm not sure what event to tap into to determine that the body's actual size has changed after the initial load.

Comment: There's no event to do it. May have to poll and measure the body element, for newer browsers, you could check the DOMSubtreeModified event and see if the dimensions changed

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a setInterval()? Something like:

```
var originalWidth = {set original width}
var originalHeight = {set original height};
setInterval(function(){
    var currentWidth = {grab new values};
    var currentHeight = {grab new values};
    if(originalWidth !== currentWidth){
        //Change the width now...
        //Next, set originalWidth to be the same as current for future checks
        originalWidth = currentWidth;
    }
    //Now, do the same for original and current height
},100)
```

Comment: Why not? cuz it's ugly! May end up being the only solution, though

Comment: Well, you could try to make it cleaner with something like:

`var originalDimensions = [x,y]` and `var currentDimensions = [x,y]`